# Driver Installation

Tags: drivers, dll, inf

I want to Install a Audio driver for my Windows 10. I downloaded it and extracted it but when I tried to install it says, Software not compatable. In my download the file extension is .dll but when I tried to install it asks for .inf , What should I do?[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olm5l.png)

Comment: Sounds like your device isn’t contained in the .inf which means the driver isnt actually designed for your device

Comment: Usually, most manufacturers have download facilities on their websites which have driver package installers. Who is the manufacturer of your machine?

Comment: Realtek drivers are really not hard to find. google "realtek drivers" & Realtek will be the top hit. See https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software

Comment: @Joseph My manufacturer is ASUS, I downloaded it from their website.

Comment: @Tetsujin If it is a executable file, can I simply Launch it? Will it update the driver?

Comment: Sure. iirc, most of the files from Realtek are 'self-installing' exes.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is running on 64-Bit Windows and by the looks of it, those drivers were designed to run on 32-Bit machines. Check your manufacturer's website for 64-Bit Drivers.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mason K. has suggested, I am also of the same view as per your screenshot that the driver you are trying to install is not compatible with your system. Check your systems property and then go for the driver as per systems specification. Moreover, you can also try by uninstalling the driver and then reboot. On rebooting the system will automatically install the best driver.

Answer (score -3):

If Your Wifi working than install driver boster from serach from google.
this software automatically update your all drivers

Comment: Snake oil. Will try to persuade you to install a dozen things you either simply don't need or may screw up your computer. Avoid like the plague.

Comment: Absolutely do not install Driver Booster.  As already indicated it’s snake oil.  There is absolutely nothing unique about that piece of malware.